# ImmutableCollection declarations for GWT-RPC serialization

Tags: serialization, guava, gwt-rpc

My understanding is that DTOs to be serialized for [GWT RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) ought to declare their fields of the lowest possible implementation type for performance reasons. For example, one should favor `ArrayList` over `List` or `Collection`, in defiance of the advice we normally receive to the contrary (e.g., Effective Java, Item 52).

With the JDK collections, this is no problem—most of the time, a `Map` is a `HashMap`, a `Set` is a `HashSet` and a `List` is an `ArrayList`. However, I am using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s Immutable* collections (e.g., [ImmutableList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)), where I really don't know which implementation I'll end up getting. Do I need to just suck it up and let GWT emulate all of them, or is there any way to do damage control here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right.  Just use the most specific type that is part of the API.

Subtypes that are annotated with `@GwtCompatible(serializable = true)` are serializable over GWT RPC unless otherwise specified (by another `@GwtCompatible(serializable = false)`).  You can safely use `Immutable*` types as GWT RPC interfaces.